# Web Page scraping - WP8 - HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

please tell me what's the problem in fetching lyrics from http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/paparoach/coffeethoughts.html. I want that only lyrics will be fetched only.
thank you in advance

```
   protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string htmlPage = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/paparoach/coffeethoughts.html/");
        }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

        List<Lyrics> lyrics = new List<Lyrics>();

        foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@style='margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px']"))
        {
            Lyrics newMovie = new Lyrics();
           newMovie.Summary= div.SelectSingleNode("br\\").InnerText.Trim();
           //newMovie.Summary =    div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='lyrics']").InnerText.Trim();
           //newMovie.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='title']").InnerText.Trim();
            lyrics.Add(newMovie);
        }

        lstMovies.ItemsSource = lyrics;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.

```
//div[@style='margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px']
```

should be

```
//div[@id='main']/div[3]
```

I wrote an article about scraping if you want : [Get content from a webpage or “How to Scrape the Sky”](http://aloisdg.tumblr.com/post/108349007140/get-content-from-a-webpage-or-how-to-scrape-the).

---

By the way, azlyrics.com is powered by musicxmatch. Maybe you should check their [API](https://developer.musixmatch.com/) instead of scraping? *Safe drinking water starts at the source.*